# Link with route params

Tags: angular

I have the following url structure:

- `/:lang/register`
- `/:lang/login`.

`register` and `login` are a children of `lang` route. Is it possible to do something like:

```
 <a  [routerLink]="['/:lang/register']" >Register</a>
```

so I'll keep the `lang` the same on all pages?

Comment: I think this is possible - in my app i have a route e.g Admin/add, admin/add/stock - admin is parent route and add and stock are childs

Comment: Are you asking about the definition of the routes or the actually, implementation? Since your implementation is the implementation of a router however it will not work the way you provided.

Comment: See https://angular.io/guide/router#relative-navigation

Comment: @Nico Im asking how to implement the link. the routing is workling for me, so im asking about navigation.

Comment: Sure, routes definition looks good. Be aware that the way you are creating your routerLink is wrong though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe relative paths will help you.

You can use `..` inside `routerLink`

It can be more customized with `relativeTo` optional argument to `router.navigate`. https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

If you have deep navigation structure you can provide `ActivatedRoute` from parameter level with some token and then pass it as `relativeTo` argument.

Created [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/router-relative-paths?file=app/app.component.ts) with examples.

You can create custom `routerLink` directive for this purpose.